# differentiability over an interval

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(0,∞)→R$ satisfy $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$ $x,y∈(0,∞)$.

(a) If $f$ is differentiable at x = 1, show that f is differentiable on $(0,∞)$ and $f′(x) = f′(1)/x$

(b) Show that f is in fact infinitely differentiable.

I know that $f(0*0)$=$f(0)+f(0)$ hence $f(0)=0$ but then I'm stuck

Comment: $0$ isn't in the domain.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=f(1\cdot x)=f(1)+f(x)$, so that $f(1)=0$. Let $x\ne0$ and $h\in\mathbb{R}$ small enough. Then
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{f(x\,(1+h/x))-f(x)}{h}=\frac{f(1+h/x)}{h}=\frac1x\,\frac{f(1+h/x)-f(1)}{h/x}.
$$
Now let $h\to0$.